# Some difficulties in the proof of the theorem 1.35 of the paper of Ofelia T. Alas and others's

Tags: general-topology

The paper could download [here](http://www.few.vu.nl/~vanmill/papers/papers2011/al-ju-vm-tk-wi.pdf), as the title explains, I have two questions in the proof of the Theorem 1.35.

Question 1, How to show $\pi \restriction{D}$ is an injective map?

Question 2, How to know $E=\pi(D)$ is discrete?

Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, suppose that $f,g\in D$ and $f\ne g$. Then $g\notin U_f$, so there is an $x\in Q_f$ such that $|g(x)-f(x)|\ge\epsilon_x$. Then $x\in Q_f\subseteq Y$, and $g(x)\ne f(x)$, so $\pi(g)=g\upharpoonright Y\ne f\upharpoonright Y=\pi(x)$, and it follows that $\pi\upharpoonright D$ is injective.

For the second question, for $f\in D$ let

$$V_f=\pi[U_f]=\{g\upharpoonright Y:|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon_f\text{ for each }x\in Q_f\}\;;$$

Then $V_f$ is an open nbhd of $\pi(f)$ in $C_p(Y)$, and we saw in answering the first question that if $g\in D\setminus\{f\}$, then $g\notin V_f$. Thus, $\pi[D]$ is discrete.